# Make invisible an element if an element of a child component is hovered

Tags: css, angular

Having the following `App.component.ts`

```
<app-title-bar></app-title-bar>
<app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
<div id="app-content">
     ...
</div>
```

How could I apply the property `visibility: hidden` to the element `#app-content` if an element of the `app-navigation-bar` is hovered ?

If the components were merged in a single component, I could simply do

```
#nav-bar:hover #app-content{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Unfortunately the component style isolation and encapsulation prevents to do it.
Any solution using `:host` or `:host-context`? I still don't think these features are appropriate..

Comment: use `NgClass` directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `:host` access now is treated to be deprecated, the only way is to set boolean variable into the `EventEmitter()` in @Output() parameter of app-navigation-bar. Then change it inside `onHover()` event.

Then change app-component visibility according to this value.

Comment: Any breaking of view-incapsulation is deprecated now: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep. Of course, you can disable view-encapsulation at all in Angular settings, or play with deprecated staff. But Angular team does not recommend it.

Comment: well it's boring to do it by this way, but it's working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *direct sibling* (`+`) or *general sibling* (`~`) selector like this:

```css
#nav-bar:hover + #app-content {
  display: none;
}
```

demo here: https://codepen.io/malejpstros/pen/VwZaeRO
more about the selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: neat. didnt know you could do this

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the following code in your `shared.css` file:

```
app-navigation-bar:hover #app-content{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

An approach 1. In your parent component:

```
app-navigation-bar:hover ::ng-deep #app-content {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

An approach 2. This code should be placed in child component:

```
:host-context(app-navigation-bar:hover) #app-content {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

UPDATE:

Try to set into your `App.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector:'test-component',
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // <------
})
```

and CSS:

```
app-navigation-bar:hover #app-content{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: on the App.component.css yes

Comment: @zackevein could you recreate your behaviour at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pncoby ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css

```
app-navigation-bar:hover #app-content{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

in your **style.css** or **app.component.css**